# Seam - Problems with IdentityManager.isUserEnabled()

Tags: java, security, jpa, seam, identity-management

I have a JBoss Seam app that leverages Seam's `IdentityManager` and `JpaIdentityStore` components for handling user account creation and authentication.  My `components.xml` file is setup correctly, and I'm able to use `IdentityManager` for creating accounts with no problem.

I have created a page to allow me to perform rudimentary account maintenance, such as enabling/disabling accounts.  However, whenever I call the `isUserEnabled(String username)` method on `IdentityManager`, it always returns false.  The corresponding method in `JpaIdentityStore` also returns false.  Both occur even though I can see that the accounts have been enabled in the database.  My user account class is annotated as follows:

```
@Name("user")
@Entity(name = "UserAccount")
@Table(name = "tbl_user_acct", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username") })
public class UserAccountBean extends BaseDomainEntity implements
        VersionedDomainEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3573332411594504888L;

    @UserEnabled
    private boolean enabled;

        ...

}
```

I don't have any issues with any of the other aspects of the `IdentityManager` class (changing passwords, creating/deleting accounts, etc.)  The only error I run into is when I try to determine if a user is enabled or not.  I don't receive any exceptions or error messages, I just get the wrong result returned.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Any idea how best to start troubleshooting this issue?

**EDIT**:  Some additional info...

I notice that when I call `disableUser(String username)`, I do actually see the database reflect that in the ENABLED column.  Additionally, when I call `enableUser(String username)`, I immediately see that the account is enabled.  However, if I navigate to another page and then come back and call `isUserEnabled()`, it still shows false.

Comment: With a breakpoint in the line that calls isUserEnabled(username) and Hibernate SQL logging turned on, can you see a 'select ... from tbl_user_acct where username = ?' in the log when you let the method to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue related to lazy fetching.  I have a UserProfile object with a userAccount property on it.  The relation is Lazy-fetched.  Once I changed it to Eager fetching, I received the appropriate response from isUserEnabled().